# cant install mod_python3 on freeswitch

Tags: python, freeswitch

I have installed Freeswitch-mod-python3 on my freeswitch box running version 1.10.7.  I then uncommented out the python3 line in the module.conf file.  Then did a reloadxml, this reloaded successfully.  When I do a "module_exists mod_python3" I get false.  Then I tried to load it and the error I get is below, which is weird cause python3.so is a file in that directory and has the same permissions as every other file in that dir.  I have rebooted the box as well as restarted FS and no luck.  What else can I try?

```
freeswitch@fusionPBX> load module mod_python3
+OK Reloading XML
-ERR [module load file routine returned an error]

2022-02-21 20:27:34.505352 99.03% [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1750 Error Loading module /usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/module mod_python3.so
**/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/module mod_python3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

root@fusionPBX:/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod# ls -ltr | grep python
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207968 Oct 24 17:26 mod_python.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 207624 Oct 24 17:26 mod_python3.so
root@fusionPBX:/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod# pwd

/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

`apt-get install freeswitch-mod-python3`

Then I loaded the module by adding it to the end of my autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml

```
<configuration name="modules.conf" description="Modules">
  <modules>
    ...
    <load module="mod_python3"/>
  </modules>
</configuration>
```

Once I restarted I can see the module loaded when I run:

```
freeswitch@dc01-sip01> show modules
...
api,pyrun,mod_python3,/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_python3.so
api,python,mod_python3,/usr/lib/freeswitch/mod/mod_python3.s
```

This on a vanilla Debian Buster box with the FreeSWITCH repo added.